# Mounted volume not accessible

Tags: terminal, catalina, mount, smb

I'm trying to mount an external volume:

```
/bin/mkdir -p /Volumes/share
/sbin/mount -o nosuid,-d=777 -t smbfs //user:pwd@host.local/share /Volumes/share
```

The script runs as a Daemon, no error. The share is visible from Console (whith root privileges) and the mounted share has all privileges enabled:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  16384  2 jan 21:19 share
```

However I cannot even list the content `ls` of the mounted share unless I use root privileges. It's this normal?

This problem appeared only after upgrading from High Sierra to Catalina and I wonder if the later is more restrictive and how to make it work.

Edit 1: this is the result of `mount | grep share`:

```
//user@host.local/share on /Volumes/share (smbfs, nosuid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after many turns, I've found what's going on:

The executing shell/app in the script (e.g. zsh, sh, python - in my case **/bin/bash**) needs to have Full Disk Access privileges. In order to do so I went to Apple Menu > System Preferences > Security & Privacy, selected Privacy tab, unlocked the settings and added /bin/bash to the list.

Now I can read and write the mounted share.